# Why is nmap not working in 18.04?

Tags: nmap

After fresh installs of Ubuntu 18.04 and nmap (snap install) on two separate machines, both return the same nmap error:

> dnet: Failed to open device [device-name]
>   QUITTING!

when I run the command:

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

Is there a new syntax I should be using?

The command works without sudo, but outputs less information.

Nmap version is 7.25SVN

Comment: Do you have the same problem with a non-snap version of `nmap`? (Snaps are restricted in what they can do, and the snap package might not have the correct permissions.)

Answer (score 14):

As [the comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031714/why-is-nmap-not-working-in-18-04#comment1927087_1157779) by [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix) suggested the way to make the snap version of nmap work (on Ubuntu 20.04 "focal fossa") is

```
sudo snap connect nmap:network-control
```

Answer (score 4):

As JanC already hinted at, the snap version of nmap has an issue with opening network devices when it is run as root. After removing the snap version and installing the aptitude version it worked as expected.

Comment: For the snap version it says after installation you need to run: `sudo snap connect nmap:network-control ` https://snapcraft.io/nmap